# list has no attribute text when using find_elements

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping the xbox website to get some account information.  In the information, I am trying to scrape someone's name and their status, which fall under the same tag and class, so I made a list to append each of these values to.  However, the account does not always have a name attached to it, but always a status so I made an if statement to tell whether there is more than 1 element scraped.  However, it only works if there are two elements; not one.

```py
status_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'right-side')]/p")

  statusName = []

  if len(status_name) > 1:
    for r in status_name:
      statusName.append(r.text)
    status = statusName[1]
    irlname = statusName[0]
  else:
    status=statusName.text
```

```
File "main.py", line 286, in xbox
    statusName.append(status_name.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list. `find_element_by_xpath` returns just the first element (note the plural).

Comment: oh my Im dumb.  thanks for pointing this out.  How could i change this when there is only one element?

Comment: you don't need the if else at all. The case when len = 1 should work just the same, I think

Comment: the only thing is that the for goes through each letter then

Comment: `elements` always return list - even for one or none elements and you don't have to use `len()` - it will iterate list, not chars,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements` (with `s`) always return `list` - even for one element - and you don't have to use `len()` - it will always iterate list, not chars.

BTW:  if it can't find elements then it gives empty list and you don't need `len()` too.

```
status_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'right-side')]/p")

statusName = []

for r in status_name:
    statusName.append(r.text)
```

or shorter

```
status_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'right-side')]/p")

statusName = [r.text for r in status_name]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You need `len()` after getting text - to see if it has name

```
if len(statusName) > 1:
    status  = statusName[1]
    irlname = statusName[0]
else:
    status  = statusName[0]
    irlname = '???'
```

---

Eventually you can write all in your way but it will aways need indexes. And you can do it without list `statusName`

```
status_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'right-side')]/p")

if len(status_name) > 1:
    status  = status_name[1].text
    irlname = status_name[0].text
else:
    status  = status_name[0].text
    irlname = '???'
```